# Rotation lock on a iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, screen-lock

How can I find the rotation lock switch on a iPhone 5?  It is lock and does not rotates the pictures when I rotate the phone.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running iOS 6: Double-tap the home button. Swipe to the right (as if scrolling left). There's a button with a rotating arrow with a lock that toggles rotation lock.

If you're running iOS 7 or 8: Swipe up from the bottom of your screen to open Control Center; you may need to unlock your phone first. The rightmost button on the top of Control Center is a similar rotating arrow with a lock.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent a white trying to figure and  not luck. I must lock it myself when I use this screen to use the flashlight.